# Get list of moves from PGN

Tags: language-agnostic, chess

I have a PGN (Portable Game Notation) of a chess game. What I would like is to get just a list of the moves. For example:

PGN :

```
1. e4 e5 2. f4 exf4 3. Nf3 d5 4. exd5 Nf6 5. Nc3 Nxd5 6. Nxd5 Qxd5 7. d4 Bg4 8.
Bxf4 Nc6 9. Be2 O-O-O 10. c3 Qe4 11. Qd2 Rxd4 12. Nxd4 Nxd4 13. cxd4 Bb4 14.
Kf2 Bxd2 15. Bxg4+ f5 16. Bxd2 fxg4 17. Rhe1 Qxd4+ 18. Be3 Qxb2+ 19. Kf1 Re8
0-1
```

output:

```
['e4','e5','f4','exf4','Nf3','d5', .... , 'Re8']
```

My idea was the take the string and split it at the spaces and then arrange a new array that way, but I'm wondering if there are any better ways of doing this. There's no specific language I'm just interested in general. Could be python, javascript, doesn't really matter.

Also, sometimes PGN comes with notation in the middle of the string or "variations" which are denoted in brackets, I'd like to ignore these. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You need a PGN parser. There are many in existence that you could use as a resource to learn. There's probably even a specification. Do use these resources to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, I couldn't find good PGN parsers for Ruby or Javascript. Here are two other libraries that I briefly tested:

- PHP: https://github.com/DHTMLGoodies/chessParser (seems to be broken; when I tried I always got an empty array of games)
- Perl: http://metacpan.org/pod/Chess::PGN::Parse
  (seems to work, at least I could see the moves of a PGN game. Not easy to get started, though.)

Maybe it is really the best approach to write the parser yourself. You can eliminate the comments with regular expressions as they are not nested.

> (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation#Comments))
>   Comments are inserted by either a ";" (a comment that continues to the end of the line) or a "{" (which continues until a matching "}"). Comments do not nest.

After the comments (including the variants) are gone, you can parse the moves as you intended (split for whitespaces and filter the move numbers).

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using the Ruby PGN gem at https://rubygems.org/gems/pgn It has a parser module, you can do PGN-> FEN, play through the game, set up positions with FEN import, etc. i've been using a branch of this as well at https://github.com/tobiasvl/pgn/tree/pgn-annotations this branch is able to parse PGNs containing variations and comments.

Here's a javascript version, https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js